# How to connect to HTTPS via proxy with WinINet

Tags: c, https, proxy, wininet

i'm trying to connect to the HTTPS service via Proxy using WinINet. My code looks like this:

```
hInternet = InternetOpenW(L"Test", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY,L"PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT", L"<local>", 0);

if (hInternet == NULL)
{
    printf("InternetOpenW failed! Error code: %d\n", GetLastError());
}
else
{
    HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnectW(hInternet, L"HTTPS_SERVICE_IP", 443, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
    if (hConnect == NULL)
    {
        printf("InternetConnectW failed! Error code: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequestW(hConnect, NULL, L"", NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0);
        if (hRequest == NULL)
        {
            printf("HttpOpenRequestW failed! Error code: %d\n", GetLastError());
        }
        else
        {
            BOOL bRequestSent = HttpSendRequestW(hRequest, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
            if (!bRequestSent)
            {
                printf("HttpSendRequestW failed! Error code: %d\n", GetLastError());
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Connection ok!\n");
            }

            InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
        }

        InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
    }

    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
}
```

It sends GET request to the proxy, perform ntml authentication, but  connection fails. Proxy expect the client to send CONNECT request. How can I send CONNECT method with that code?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the `INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE` flag in your `HttpOpenRequestW` call, such as here:

```
HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequestW(hConnect, NULL, L"", NULL, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE, 0);
```

Obviously, the application code on your side needs to recognize whether you're dealing with HTTP or HTTPs and add this flag only when needed.